# Is it possible to extract the format options of an Excel chart into VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a macro that will automatically create a chart based off some data in a table. However, the chart format that I need to use is very complicated (20 columns of data all displayed in a particular custom format), and I don't know how to recreate that format with the chart editor, let alone VBA.

Basically, I want to be able to take an example of this chart format, and somehow get the VBA code that one would use to create a chart of this format directly in VBA, so I can include this code in the macro.

I was considering making a chart template .crtx file and including it with the spreadsheet in a .zip when the user downloads it, but templates seem to only work when they are located under `User\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts`, and I don't want to put the user through having to manually move this file for the macro to work. Alternatively, if anybody knows how to get a template to work when it isn't installed in this location that would be great as well!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can write a script that will save the chart template to the correct location for the user that they can run

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I will try that, thank you! Is it possible to check to see if the user already has that template in that location, so if they run it multiple times it won't attempt to save the template over and over?

Comment: yes, that is possible too. like for `FileSystemObject.FileExists` for example

Answer (score 0):

Include the chart with the original format in the workbook when you send it, and put the example chart on a sheet that is very hidden.

Then, write your macro such that it creates a chart of the same type with the new data and copies the formatting of the original chart.

How to make a sheet "very hidden":  https://www.excel-university.com/make-an-excel-worksheet-very-hidden/

How to copy chart formatting:  https://www.officetooltips.com/excel_2016/tips/a_quick_way_to_duplicate_all_of_the_custom_chart_formatting.html

Note:  If you're struggling with how to use vba to copy the chart formatting, record a macro while executing the instructions at the second link.